# My bullets dont make the enemy die?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a physical bullet that spawns and that has an always motion.  When it hits the enemy it does not make him die.  I am trying to have a collision sensor on the enemy to make it end the object with the Edit Object actuator.  Also, on the collision sensor on the enemy, no propertys are in the list even though I added a property to the bullet?  Should the property be in a certain way?  I left it default cause I did not think that mattered.  Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You must type in that property which you added to bullet(there aren't any lists in this sensor) or set collision to bullet's material(M/P, than choose the one that bullet has).